# how to access gridview's or datagrid's data in runtime?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagrid, dataset

Assume I have a gridview or datagrid ,I set a dataset(or datatable) as datasource to it ,and then use .databind() ,and now I see this grid in the site,I want to get the dataset(or datatable) from grid when I click a button.is there anyway,for both gridview and datagrid?
I think I can convert datagrid.items into dataset ,is it true?if your answer is yes,please say how can I do?but I'm not sure about gridview

Comment: Is this the kind of solution you are looking for? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bcb6f3c6-da91-4a80-9edc-3a5fd98490dd/fill-dataset-from-datagridview?forum=winformsdesigner

Answer (score 0):

Just run another GridView1.DataBind() with another DataSet or DataTable from a Button or DropDownList.

Comment: I don't want to connect into database again,this website has too many users.